# Sending json data using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a small doubt. I am trying to send json data to my back end page like this. But i am getting error. where in only $fb_list1 is json data. So how do i send it from here.

```
$('.fresh_start')
    .html("<div class='response1'><img src='/images/preloader.gif' alt='Loading.....'></img></div>")
    .load('abc.php',{product:'lcd',type:'product_display',fb_list:"<?php echo $fb_list1 ?>"});
```

Comment: Please provide WHAT error you are getting and please add some line breaks to your statement. You might want to provide the content of $fb_list1 as well. Maybe the JSON code is wrong. You can use this validator to check whether your JSON code is correct: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Your question is not clear. `product` and `type` will just be strings. These values are available via `$_POST['product']` and `$_POST['type']`. Do you want to send the whole object as JSON? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there your answer
[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)